# What makes a question too broad for code review?

Tags: discussion

I was pondering the close reason today and I can't think of an instance where a question that is *on-topic* for Code Review is too broad.

When is a question too broad? How could a too-broad question be edited to be acceptable?

Comment: FYI, [posts closed as too broad](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/317129/closed-too-broad) (that have not been auto-deleted)

Answer (score 13):

I have been using the "Too Broad" close reason for questions which ask for reviews of multiple different things--posts asking for two different reviews.

Generally, these questions could be fixed by splitting them into multiple questions.

For example, if you have an iOS app that talks to a webserver that you also wrote, if you post some code from the iOS app and some code from the web server in the same question, I will vote to close as too broad.  If you remove one or the other from the original question, I'll retract my close vote and cast a reopen vote.

Comment: So just to be sure, you mean when there are two conceptually different bits of code being reviewed, and not when they're asking to check the same bit of code for, for example, performance and security concerns?

Comment: Correct.  I mean when the question includes some Objective-C code for connecting to a webserver and some PHP code that runs on the server end.  When these are both in the same question.

Comment: I agree with this, and that's how I use it too. I'm just wondering what other kinds of questions could potentially been seen as "Too Broad". I'm glad this came up.

Comment: Would this also apply if client and server were written in the same language, and part of the code is shared between client and server?