# When is a question too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I wish to bring this question before the Code Review site.  In the past, we have had this question: [What makes a question too broad for code review?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5364/what-makes-a-question-too-broad-for-code-review), which asks how to use the "Too Broad" close vote reason.  It received one answer that said to use the Too Broad reason on [comparative-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-review) questions (which, BTW, have been determined to be on-topic for the site, so it is outdated).

Later, we have this question: [How Broad is "Too Broad"?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6282/how-broad-is-too-broad), which received answers about what makes a question too broad, and how to ask a good question.

My question is about whether we should use the "Too Broad" reason for the specific class of questions commonly known as "Gimme teh Codez."  For example, we received [this (now-deleted) question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148948/artificial-intelligence), which was closed with the following reason:

> Questions containing broken code or asking for advice about code not yet written are off-topic, as the code is not ready for review. After the question has been edited to contain working code, we will consider reopening it.

It also fits, nominally, into the following close reason, which is typically reserved for questions with working code behind a link:

> Questions must include the code to be reviewed. Links to code hosted on third-party sites are permissible, but the most relevant excerpts must be embedded in the question itself.

We have [11 questions closed as "Too Broad"](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/revision/590654/740358/too-broad-questions). Should we be using the "Too Broad" close reason for such questions?  Is the "Broken Code" close reason being used too broadly?

Comment: Where does it say that "Too Broad" could be used to close [tag:comparative-review] questions? That's not what nhgrif said.

Comment: "Posts asking for two different reviews" was his description of [tag:comparative-review] questions in his extensive advocation in the chatroom around that time for them to be made off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To addresses your first two paragraphs, too broad is for when a single Code Review question asks what should be multiple Code Review questions.

The *broken code* close reason isn't *a single close reason*. It's two. Which is easier to see if we keep the links in the close reason:

> Questions containing [broken code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3650) or asking for advice about [code not yet written](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3651) are off-topic, as the code is not ready for review. After the question has been edited to contain working code, we will consider reopening it.

And if you follow the [code not yet written](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3651) link you'll see it's the correct close reason for these questions. And so it's not that the close reason is being used too broadly, but that the close reason its self may be too broad.

Comment: Good answer.  Sometimes it seems this close reason is used too much, which is mainly why I posted this question.  Of course, it would sure help if we had the prompts for broken code and missing code.

Comment: @Hosch250 I think that too, and so I split them when I wrote what [I think the close reasons should be](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6761/42401). I'll ask a mod if they'd want to retry it.